# Chrome Cache disabled and history/data cleared and still does not show new site

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome

I updated a reactjs site and put up a static site instead.

The react site was created with create-react-app and was compiled and served with ngnix, as is the static site.

I can see the new site with Safari and Firefox and Chrome on my phone.  The issue is that Chrome on my laptop still shows the old React site.

If I open incognito mode it shows the new site.  I have:

- Cleared all cache/cookies/etc in chrome
- Opened developer tabs and made sure "Disable Cache" is checked
- Done the "Emtpy Cache and Hard Reload" thing with the dev tools open

Why is it still caching?  How can I make chrome forget this domain?

Comment: Since this is one of those problems that really don't make sense can I make a few questions? If you run your link with a querystring does it still show the cached site? Did you clear localstorage?

Comment: Querystring still shows the cached site (https://example.com?asdf=true) and I did `localStorage.clear()` in the console`

Comment: Is this by any chance running from Azure? I had a similar issue in the past... Fixed it with a app service restart. Have you tried that?

Comment: Have you also checked https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1910?

Comment: It's running on an Ubuntu Linode that has an HAProxy reverse proxy in front of NGINX.  It has been restarted, and as a matter of fact the haproxy is newer than the site, it used to just be directly into nginx...

Comment: Very glad it is fixed! These nonsense stuff can really drive us crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on Carlos Alves Jorge's link above:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
  registration.unregister();
});
```

I ran that in the javascript console and it worked!

Thank you!